# My activity keeps force closing because of this error

Tags: android, sql

My activity keeps force closing because of this class exception

```
    07-02 01:24:59.244: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(660):
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.fttech.collection/com.fttech.collection.book_list}: 
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '_id' does not exist
```

thsi is my class

```
    public class bookDbHelper{

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "data";
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "books";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;


    public static final String KEY_BOOKTITLE = "title";
    public static final String KEY_AUTHOR = "author";
    public static final String KEY_ISBN = "isbn";
    public static final String KEY_RATING = "rating";
    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_ID";


    private DatabaseHelper mDbHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase mDb;

    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = 
        " create table " + DATABASE_TABLE + " ("
        + KEY_ROWID + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
        + KEY_BOOKTITLE + " text not null,  "
        + KEY_AUTHOR + " text not null, "
        + KEY_ISBN + " text not null, "
        + KEY_RATING + " text not null);";

    private final Context mCtx;

    public bookDbHelper(Context ctx){
        this.mCtx = ctx;
    }
    private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
        DatabaseHelper(Context context){
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);

        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase arg0, int arg1, int arg2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    }


        public bookDbHelper open()throws SQLException{
        mDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(mCtx);
        mDb = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

        return this;
    }

        public void close(){
            mDbHelper.close();

        }
        public long addBook(String book_name, String author, String isbn, String rating){

            ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
            initialValues.put(KEY_BOOKTITLE, book_name);
            initialValues.put(KEY_AUTHOR, author);
            initialValues.put(KEY_ISBN, isbn);
            initialValues.put(KEY_RATING, rating);

            return mDb.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);


        }
        public boolean DeleteBook(long rowId){
            return mDb.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;


        }
        public Cursor fetchAllBooks(){
            return mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String []{KEY_BOOKTITLE, KEY_AUTHOR, KEY_ISBN, KEY_RATING, KEY_ROWID}, null, null, null, null, null);
        }
        public Cursor fetchBook(long rowId)throws SQLException {
            Cursor mCursor = 
                mDb.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_BOOKTITLE, KEY_AUTHOR, KEY_RATING, KEY_ISBN, KEY_ROWID}, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null, null, null, null, null);
            if(mCursor != null){
                mCursor.moveToFirst();
            }
            return mCursor;

}
        public boolean updateBooks(long rowId, String book_name, String author, String rating, String isbn){
            ContentValues args = new  ContentValues();
            args.put(KEY_BOOKTITLE, book_name);
            args.put(KEY_AUTHOR, author);
            args.put(KEY_ISBN, isbn);
            args.put(KEY_RATING, rating);
            return 
            mDb.update(DATABASE_TABLE, args, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) >0;





        }
}
```

Here is my second class that pulls data from the `SQLbase`

```
public class book_list extends ListActivity{    

    private static final int ACTIVITY_CREATE = 0;
    private static final int ACTIVTY_EDIT = 1;

    private bookDbHelper mDbHelper;
            @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.book_list);
        mDbHelper = new bookDbHelper(this);         
        mDbHelper.open();
        fillData();
        registerForContextMenu(getListView());  
    }

    private void fillData() {
        Cursor booksCursor = mDbHelper.fetchAllBooks();
        startManagingCursor(booksCursor);

        String [] from = new String[]{bookDbHelper.KEY_BOOKTITLE};

        int[] to = new int[]{R.id.text1};

        SimpleCursorAdapter books = 
            new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.book_row, booksCursor, from, to);
        setListAdapter(books);

    }
    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id){
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

        Intent i = new Intent(this, book_edit.class);
        i.putExtra(bookDbHelper.KEY_ROWID, id);
        startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVTY_EDIT);

    }
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent){
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
        fillData();
    }

}
    public class book_list extends ListActivity{
    private static final int ACTIVITY_CREATE = 0;
    private static final int ACTIVTY_EDIT = 1;

    private bookDbHelper mDbHelper;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.book_list); 
        mDbHelper = new bookDbHelper(this);
        mDbHelper.open();
        fillData();
        registerForContextMenu(getListView()); 

    }

    private void fillData() {
        Cursor booksCursor = mDbHelper.fetchAllBooks();
        startManagingCursor(booksCursor);

        String [] from = new String[]{bookDbHelper.KEY_BOOKTITLE};

        int[] to = new int[]{R.id.text1};

        SimpleCursorAdapter books = 
            new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.book_row, booksCursor, from, to);
        setListAdapter(books);

    }
    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id){
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

        Intent i = new Intent(this, book_edit.class);
        i.putExtra(bookDbHelper.KEY_ROWID, id);
        startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVTY_EDIT);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent){
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
        fillData();
    }

}
```

Comment: Please take the time to properly format you code (using the `{}` button in the editor).

Comment: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '_id' does not exist this shows the problem.. ur trying to use _id column that is not available

Answer (score 0):

Maybe

```
public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_ID";
```

must be lower case

```
public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you download the database file onto your PC :

```
adb pull /data/data/[your.application.package.name]/databases/[your.database.name] .
```

and then use something like [SQLite Manager](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/) to look at the database itself. It is possible the database was created with some earlier version of your code and never updated with the right columns for example...

Comment: Where do i find the database files at?

Comment: that's in the answer. If you get to the shell (adb shell), go to /data/data/[your.package.name]/databases